# datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp does not support dates less than 1970

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to to build a program that should process a data which was acquired since 1830. I made a reference date `datetime(1970, 1, 1)` to compute the timedelta.

The timedelta works good and I get some negative numbers which is normal. The problem occurs when I want to reconvert the dates to plot data in a proper way using `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t)`. So  here "t" is negative.

Looking for this on internet I found that it's a Python bug or limitation under Windows. I have the 3.5 version and windows 10. I found nothing which can be helpful. So if you know a solution to that or an alternative way using panda library I will be very thankful.

The error it returns to me is : `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems indeed to be a bug on your machine. On my machine (Python 3.6.3 in Ubuntu 17.10) negative numbers work correctly as UTC time-stamp.

As a workaround you can try [`datetime.datetime.toordinal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal) and [`datetime.datetime.fromordinal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromordinal). The ordinals start on January 1, 0001 and should therefore be able to cover your date range using only positive numbers:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(1830, 1, 1)
event_1 = datetime.datetime(1835, 2, 10)
diff = (event_1 - start).days
# 1866

datetime.datetime.fromordinal(start.toordinal() + diff)
# datetime.datetime(1835, 2, 10, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I moved to panda it's more simpler for handling dates. There is no need for a date0. It's like MATLAB you can easily parse dates and display it in the x_label.  I used `pandas.read_csv() `